# php class showing empty query

Tags: php, oop

This is my class:

```
<?php
class Query {
    protected $_link;
    protected $_result;
    protected $_query;

    public function __construct($query) {
        $_link=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mismatch') 
            or die('Unable to connect database');
        $this->_query=$query;
        $_result = mysqli_query($_link, $_query)
                or die('unable to enter the query');
        }
        protected function getResult(){
            return $this->_result;
        }
}

?>
```

I imported my class in index file in this form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Become the member here</h1>

<?php 
   require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mismatch/cls/csl_Query.php';
   $q='SELECT * FROM `user`';
   $query1=new Query($q);
   echo $query1->getResult();

?>


    </body>
</html>
```

when open the file in browser it shows following error:

Notice: Undefined variable: _query in C:\xampp\htdocs\mismatch\cls\csl_query.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\mismatch\cls\csl_query.php on line 11
unable to enter the query

Kindly show my error

Comment: With this class every time you want to execute a query you have to reconnect to the DB server, which is highly inefficient. Why not stick with just using MySQLi's already existing OOP interface and when you have a specific need to add functionality to it and understand OOP more yourself, you can do it right.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a few `$this->`'s

In order for the `getResult()` method to find `$this->_result` you need to use the `$this->` in front of the variable in the constructor method.

Without the `$this->` you are referencing a local variable that only exists inside the constructor method

```
<?php
class Query {
    protected $_link;
    protected $_result;
    protected $_query;

    public function __construct($query) {
        $this->_link=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mismatch') 
        or die('Unable to connect database');
        $this->_query=$query;
        $this->_result = mysqli_query($_link, $_query)
            or die('unable to enter the query');
    }

    protected function getResult(){
        return $this->_result;
    }
}
?>
```

> Also using underscores in property names is a bit Old School ( and was normally used to indicate `Private` properties). This is not really done any more.

Comment: @PeeHaa what's is lacking from Riggs' answer?

Comment: Adding something to your answer where you note things being _old school_. It's not necessarily old school, with the introduction for support of OOP in PHP 4, properties were defined with `var`. This said, the visibility of the defined property was always `public`. Until the introduction of keywords `protected` and `private` introduced in PHP 5 and for legacy reasons `var` was still supported to maintain backward compatibility. Using underscore was a _visual_ notation, to distinguish the visibility for each property defined ..